# How do I verify this argument?

Tags: logic

If I have this argument:

> If there are beehives on the trees, it is winter.  It is winter. 
>   Therefore, there are beehives on the trees.

Define:

> B = beehives on the trees
>
> W = winter

In formal logic:

> (B -> W) ^ W -> W

How can I proof if this argument is logically valid?

Comment: If you are dead, then I am alive. I am alive, therefore you are dead.

Comment: what is the definition of valid in logic ???  that may help.

Comment: @Roddy: A sentence is valid if it is provable from the empty theory.

Comment: The formal logic one says something else than what the English version states. By the way.

Comment: a logical statement is valid if given it's premises are true  the conclusion follows as true. this is different from a  sound argument where the premises are proven true and the conclusion is the only result.  see https://www.khanacademy.org/partner-content/wi-phi/wiphi-critical-thinking/wiphi-fundamentals/v/validity

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that this is true: "If it's not winter there are no beehives in the tree". One technique you can use is a truth table: $$\\\begin{array}{cc|c}
      B&W&B\implies W\\
      T&T&T\\
      T&F&F\\
      F&T&T\\
      F&F&T
    \end{array}\\$$ Note that if $W$ is true, then $B$ can be either true or false, but implication is still true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you made a mistake formalizing this argument. Your final conclusion should be $B$, not $W$, in order to match what you've written in the English version.

Secondly, this argument is not valid. It's equivalent to this:

1. If $p$ is a prime greater than $2$, then $p$ is an odd integer.
2. $-15$ is an odd integer.
3. Therefore, $-15$ is a prime greater than $2$.

This is an example of the fallacy, "Affirming the consequent".